# How Do I Query Against Data.gov

Tags: sparql

I am trying to teach myself this weekend how to run API queries against a data source in this case data.gov. At first I thought I'd use a simple SQL variant, but it seems in this case I have to use SPARQL.

I've read through the documentation, downloaded Twinkle, and can't seem to quite get it to run. Here is an example of a query I'm running. I'm basically trying to find all gas stations that are null around Denver, CO.

```
PREFIX station: https://api.data.gov/nrel/alt-fuel-stations/v1/nearest.json?api_key=???location=Denver+CO

SELECT *
WHERE
 { ?x station:network ?network like "null"
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `?x station:network ?network like "null"` isn't legal SPARQL.  You might want something like `?x station:network ?network . filter contains(?network, "null")`, if you're looking for ?network to be a string containing "null".

Comment: I'm out of the house, but will try that when I get back. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

SPARQL is a graph pattern language for RDF triples.  A query consists of a set of "basic graph patterns" described by triple patterns of the form `<subject>`, `<predicate>`, `<object>`.  RDF defines the subject and predicate with URI's and the object is either a URI (object property) or literal (datatype or language-tagged property).  Each triple pattern in a query must therefore have three entities.

Since we don't have any examples of your data, I'll provide a way to explore the data a bit.  Let's assume your prefix is correctly defined, which I doubt - it will not be the REST API URL, but the URI of the entity itself.  Then you can try the following:

```
PREFIX station: <http://api.data.gov/nrel...>
SELECT *
WHERE
{  ?s station:network ?network .
}
```

...setting the PREFIX to correctly represent the namespace for `network`.  Then look at the binding for `?network` and find out how they represent `null`.  Let's say it is a string as you show.  Then the query would look like:

```
PREFIX station: <http://api.data.gov/nrel...>
SELECT ?s
WHERE
{  ?s station:network "null" .
}
```

There is no `like` in SPARQL, but you could use a `FILTER` clause using `regex` or other string matching features of SPARQL.

And please, please, please google "SPARQL" and "RDF".  There is lots of information about SPARQL, and the [W3C's SPARQL 1.1 Query Language Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-query-20130321/) is a comprehensive source with many good examples.